# Download a File with the <input> tag in html

Tags: html, css, input

I am currently working on making a website for my startup Virtual Business, and I am trying to make the `<input>` tag let me download a file.

- Current Code, which I have used from other Stack Overflow Posts

```html
<input type="button" value="Download" classs="buyButton"onclick="href='google.com'">
```

I have all of the CSS laid out, and the button is functional, but just needs to look like the button on the far right [Image at this link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gcbMK.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `CSS` like this:

```css
.buyButton {
  background-color: #C0C0C0;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}
.buyButton:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="Download" class="buyButton" onclick="location.href='google.com'">
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap has a variety of different buttons to choose from. 
For your button to appear on the far right, use css styling `float:right;`
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/

Answer (score -1):

```
<button type="button" class="btn--download" onclick="location.href='stackoverflow.com'">Download</button

.btn--download {
    border-radius: 7px;
    box-shadow: none;
    color: black;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 10px 15px;
    transition: ease .4s background-color, ease .4s color .4s
}

.btn--download:hover {
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}
```